# Does this tag have the correct [syntax]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, meta, burninate-request

The tag [syntax](/questions/tagged/syntax) here on this site seems to have no clear, specific purpose, and it's been used to refer to many different things on the 20 uses it has so far.

Most of its current uses are already well-covered by existing tags:

- Syntax highlighting: [syntax-highlighting](/questions/tagged/syntax-highlighting)
- Markdown formatting syntax: [markdown](/questions/tagged/markdown)
- Search syntax: [search](/questions/tagged/search)
- Mathematics syntax: [mathjax](/questions/tagged/mathjax)

I don't think this tag provides any meaningful categorization of questions.

Should we agree to remove it?

Comment: There also was one about wording on SE sites, I retagged that one already.

Comment: Another related tag to be used instead of `syntax`: [tag:code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the positive consensus of this request, I've been spending the last couple of weeks removing the tag from questions which use it, and replacing it with the more specific tags I pointed out wherever applicable.

There was one locked merge stub using the tag, which I flagged for moderators to remove, and they did so.

The tag has now been purged from the system, and is no longer in use, making this request [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

Comment: No dragon here?

Comment: @Luuklag the dragon suffer from syntax error.

Answer (score 5):

As [syntax](/questions/tagged/syntax) hasn't a tag excerpt / wiki and there are already other more specific tags it might be removed from the questions that are using it when fixing other question problems as it looks that it's doesn't doing any harm.